# how can i display my array elements into textboxs?

Tags: c#

can anyone help me please,,
i'm trying to display my array elements into textbox and listview
the listview works but the textbox shows my int 6 time, here is my code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList();
            int[] myNumbers = new int[6];

            Random rnd = new Random();
            int randomNumber;
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                do
                {
                    randomNumber = rnd.Next(1, 49);
                }
                while (numbers.Contains(randomNumber));

                numbers.Add(randomNumber);
            }

            numbers.Sort();
            numbers.CopyTo(myNumbers);
            //listView1.Items.Add(myNumbers.ToString);
            foreach (int j in myNumbers)
            {




                listView1.Items.Add(j.ToString());

                label1.Text += j.ToString();


                int num1 = myNumbers[0];
                int num2 = myNumbers[1];
                int num3 = myNumbers[2];
                int num4 = myNumbers[3];
                int num5 = myNumbers[4];
                int num6 = myNumbers[5];
                textBox1.Text += num1;
                textBox2.Text += num2;
                textBox3.Text += num3;
                textBox4.Text += num4;
                textBox5.Text += num5;
                textBox6.Text += num6;

            }

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";
            textBox3.Text = "";
            textBox4.Text = "";
            textBox5.Text = "";
            textBox6.Text = "";

            listView1.Clear();
            label1.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone help me and tell me where am i going wrong?

Comment: "+=" is used for appending text, u should only use "=" @vahid

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
textBox1.Text = num1;
```

not

```
textBox1.Text += num1;
```

Edit: You don't need loop...

Comment: textBox1.Text = num1; gives error as Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

Comment: try textBox1.Text = num1.ToString(); or num1+"";

Answer (score 0):

you're setting the texts within the loop.  So you're setting the values six times, which you can see because you're appending with +=.  You could move this whole block to just after `numbers.CopyTo(myNumbers);` so each value is only set once.  Also there's no need for +=.

```
int num1 = myNumbers[0];
int num2 = myNumbers[1];
int num3 = myNumbers[2];
int num4 = myNumbers[3];
int num5 = myNumbers[4];
int num6 = myNumbers[5];
textBox1.Text = num1.ToString();
textBox2.Text = num2.ToString();
textBox3.Text = num3.ToString();
textBox4.Text = num4.ToString();
textBox5.Text = num5.ToString();
textBox6.Text = num6.ToString();
```

Comment: textBox1.Text = num1; gives error as Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

Comment: yeah my bad, forgot to put the .ToString()

Comment: plus to be honest, if you're not using num1, num2, etc. elsewhere you can just take the value straight from myNumbers[x].ToString().

Comment: @vahid, you knew about `ToString` 3 lines before .. `label1.Text += j.ToString();`

Comment: but when i try to remove the + from textBox1.Text += num1; i get an error as Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

Comment: yeah, I updated the answer with the missing .ToString().

Answer (score 0):

There were few issue in your code.

You don't need both `ArrayList numbers` and `int[] myNumbers`, you can access List by index too.
You use so much magic number : 6, 1, 49. They could be replace with variable.
Before adding value to a listView, you can clear it. You don't have to `foreach` loop on `myNumbers` you can direcly add them with AddRange method.

The result of `label1.Text+=j.ToString()` is a bit undreadable as all numbers glued together resulting in a 123564132321.
`tbResult.Text = string.Join(", ", numbers);` will [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2) then with a nice ", " as separator.

Finaly, if you you don't want to copy past N time the same line for textbox.text initialisation. You can find all the textbox that match a pattern.

```
var numbers = new List<int>();

while (numbers.Count < userInput)
{
    var tempRnd = rnd.Next(lowerBound, upperBound);
    if (!numbers.Contains(tempRnd))
    {
        numbers.Add(tempRnd);
    }
}

numbers.Sort();

listView1.Items.Clear();
listView1.Items.AddRange(numbers.Select(x => new ListViewItem { Text = x.ToString() }).ToArray());

tbResult.Text = string.Join(", ", numbers);

int i = 0;
foreach (TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(l => l.Name.StartsWith("GeneratedTB_")))
{
    tb.Text = numbers[i].ToString();
    i++;
}
```